# Warning: Increment on type bool has no effect, Need an explanation as to why $i is considered a boolean

Tags: php, php-8.3

This is a code snippet from a php function used in a software package I installed:

```
    $i = 0;
    $extra_small_header_field_values = array();
    while ($i < $i_len && $i !== false) {
        /* get argument */
        $read = trim(substr($read,$i));
        $i_len = strlen($read);
        $i = strpos($read,' ');
        $arg = substr($read,0,$i);
        ++$i;
```

The line containing ++$i; results in a warning ***Increment on type bool has no effect,***.

My question is why is $i considered a boolean here?  I realize that in PHP a boolean is a special class of integer but how does $i get to be considered a boolean given its evident prior treatment as an integer in the preceding code?  How is this issue most correctly addressed?

Comment: [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.strpos.php) may return the boolean `false`.

Comment: If it isn’t a Boolean why are you comparing it to `false`?

Comment: I did not write the code.  It is in a function in a packaged application.  I also have no experience writing PHP and completely missed the boolean comparison.  

In earlier versions of php were false and 0 equivalent?  I am confused as to what the idiom is.  $i is explicitly set to 0.  Then it is compared to a string length, and then it is compared to false.  I have no idea why this is done this way?

Comment: `false` and `0` are equivalent in many contexts. However, PHP 8 has added more stringent type checking, so now it generates this warning.

Comment: The actual behavior of the code hasn't changed. Even in old versions, ++ on a boolean has no effect.

Comment: You should report this to the maintainer of the software package, they should update the code to check `$i` before `++$i`. Also make sure you have the latest version, maybe they already fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
$i = 0;
$extra_small_header_field_values = array();
while ($i < $i_len && $i !== false) {
    $read = trim(substr($read, $i));
    $i_len = strlen($read);
    $i = strpos($read, ' ');
    if ($i === false) {
        break;
    }
    $arg = substr($read, 0, $i);
    ++$i;
}
```

This should work for you.

The problem is because of how `$i` is used in the `while` loop the condition checks if `$i` is not equal to `false` and if it is, the loop stops. But here's the catch if the loop terminates because `$i` becomes `false` the next time around it tries to increment a boolean value and that's a not good, triggering the warning. To fix this, you need to make sure you're not trying to increment a boolean variable.

Answer (score -1):

Here a link of the RFC : https://wiki.php.net/rfc/saner-inc-dec-operators.

> PHP's increment and decrement operators can have some surprising
> behaviours when used with types other than int and float. Various
> previous attempts 1) 2) 3) have been made to improve the behaviour of
> these operators, but none have been implemented. The goal of this RFC
> is to normalize the behaviour of $v++ and $v-- to be the same as $v +=
> 1 and $v -= 1, respectively.

Simply change ++$i to $i += 1;

Comment: Why would that solve the problem?